# Vue 3 - Get data using v-model on dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I have this code in my vue app, it will create dynamic input fields

```html
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-1 mb-1">
                <a class="text-uppercase text-decoration-none text-dark" href="#" @click.prevent="addField">
                    <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
                    Add device properties
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-1 mb-1" v-for="inputs in fieldsCounter" :key="inputs">
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase rounded-0 me-1" v-model="deviceDetails.fieldName" placeholder="Field Name" @change="log">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase rounded-0 ms-1" v-model="deviceDetails.fieldValue" placeholder="Field Value" @change="log">
                </div>
            </div>
```

My method to create the fields is this:

```js
 addField(){
   this.deviceDetails.push({})
 }
```

I need to create dynamic input fields but my problem is that I'm not able to get the v-model data of the new created fields. How I can solve this problem and create inputs corectly with a v-model assigned for each new input field??H

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-for` with `v-model`

```
<div class="input-group" v-for="device in devices">    
     <input type="text" v-model="device.fieldName" placeholder="Field Name" @change="log">
     <input type="text" v-model="device.fieldValue" placeholder="Field Value" @change="log">
</div>
```

Comment: I already have the v-model but probably I'm using the wrong way to bind data?

Answer (score 1):

If I uderstood You correctly try like following snippet:

```js
const { reactive } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const deviceDetails = reactive([{}])
    const addField = () => {
      deviceDetails.push({})
    }
    return {
      deviceDetails, addField
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="addField">
      Add device properties
    </a>
  </div>
  {{deviceDetails}}
  <div v-for="inputs in deviceDetails" :key="inputs">
    <div>    
      <input type="text" v-model="inputs.fieldName" placeholder="Field Name" >
      <input type="text" v-model="inputs.fieldValue" placeholder="Field Value" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to test as you've suggested, just a question, did this let me show almost one user input before other ones are added?

Comment: @newbiedev hey mate, check the snippet again please, so if I get You right, yes you can set default value in `deviceDetails` array

Comment: ok, thank you. I will do a test

Comment: my doubt is about the v-model, is possible to avoid have a dummy data when a new field is pushed?

Comment: yes You can, I updated snippet again :)

Comment: will thi push an empty object inside the array??

Comment: exactly, empty object :)

Comment: it's not the best solution, the ideal way will be to have only objects with the inserted data

Comment: the just set empty `fieldName` and `fieldValue` properties in object, like it was before :)

Comment: If I understand, there is no way to have the object without dummy data, I've tested using the properties, but I will have an empty object before all others objects are added